# How do you say " I do not know why it is so" in an academic way?

Tags: formality, academia

The situation is, I'm complaining about the problem concerning submitting important documents via the Internet because it seems like that document was not properly submitted.

However, I don't know if it was my fault because I didn't follow the procedure or because of the bugging system. I want to write a formal letter to my university about that, but I don't know how to say it in an academic way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The reason for this is currently unknown"

Answer (score 2):

*I have not been able to discover the cause of this problem.*